# RE: How do i make smooth animations in python

Tags: python, animation, terminal, colors

I want to make animations look like [This!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96riTrt-BbU)
but i don't know how to do this since i can't convert .step to .py files, so
I am currently working with this:

```py
from random import randint
from asciimatics.screen import Screen

def demo(screen):
    while True:
        screen.print_at('Hello world!',
                        randint(0, screen.width), randint(0, screen.height),
                        colour=randint(0, screen.colours - 1),
                        bg=randint(0, screen.colours - 1))
        ev = screen.get_key()
        if ev in (ord('Q'), ord('q')):
            return
        screen.refresh()

Screen.wrapper(demo)
```

So how can i hack this code to be like in the
video?

Comment: It's unclear to me which part of the video you mean exactly.

Comment: 0 to 10 seconds into the video when the machine wakes up

Comment: There is definitely missing a description of your code and your expectations from the SO community. Where are your struggling?

Comment: Well, I am trying to mimic the animation in python. Unfortunately, he used .Step files which are really hard to integrate on a terminal running on python, plus the added challenge of changing the step file to not interact with my machine since he used the files for movement.